# interface typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

Como puedo definir una interface para algo asi: esta ok esto? porque no puedo acceder al result

```
{results:[{name:"jorge",age:10}]

interface List{
 results:[{name:string, age:number}]
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes? Yo veo [que funciona](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5mQbwFDKHJQQYCuANmBgFzIDaOyIcAthHVlKAOYA0yODw7MyrAEbRkAXwC6eaXjwUI2APbiAVnXRZkAXlzFSlanUbM2IgESa1UYdYFCRARgAMM2TKA). Vaya, tal vez queda mejor si los separas en [algo como esto](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsR2QbwChkTlcBbCALmQzClAHMAaY0uR6sgV3ICNohAL6FCoSLEQoAMsDoE2JKBAzcANmAw10UbLgDaAXWGjCaiGGRY+AKxqz5AXgWlky1Rq3J9RV64pcAEQ2WFCcgax+7Jw0AIwADIrIQsZCQA), pero de que funciona, funciona.

Comment: cual es el problema?

Comment: Como podria acceder al .name de results? asi me tira error con el console.lgo...o estoy haciendo algo mal

interface List {
    results: [{ name: string, age: number }]
}

let obj: List = { results: [{ name: "jorge", age: 10 }] }

console.log(obj.results[0].name)